# How to add line break from a list in an email html body

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list where I append the item from the list into the email body. As I display the email turns into like this.

Hi,

item1
item2

I wanted something like this. not sure how to implement this.

item1 
item2

```
import win32com.client
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.Sender = Sender
mail.Subject = "List"
mail.GetInspector`

index = mail.HTMLbody.find('>', mail.HTMLbody.find('<body')) 
lists= '\n'.join(str(serv)  for serv in servers)
message = 'Hi,''<br>''<br>' ' Please help check the names below:' + '<br>' '<br>' + lists
mail.HTMLbody = mail.HTMLbody[:index + 1] + message + mail.HTMLbody[index + 1:] 
mail.Display()
```

Comment: `join` with `<br>` tags, not newlines.

Comment: You labelled your code as HTML. It is almost python ( a few syntax errors: so not what you were testing). I have removed these tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` in not `<br/>`. Or even better, use `<li>`.